# How to load modules with an iteration and execute a method in RUBY

Tags: ruby, module

i would like to load modules dynamically and execute a method for each module loaded:
The modules are in a directory called modules/

### modules/ModA.rb

```
module ModA 
 def run 
   puts "module A"
  end 
end
```

### modules/ModB.rb

```
module ModB 
 def run 
   puts "module B"
  end 
end
```

### Main.rb

```
class Main 
  def start
    Dir.glob("modules/*.rb") do |module_file|
    load(module_file)
    # How to store modules in a list and call <Module>::run() ?
    end
  end
end


a = Main.new
a.start
```

So After loading modules, i would like to call run() of each modules. How can this be done ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to call the `run` method inside your module. To do so, write:

```
module ModA 
 def self.run 
   puts "module A"
  end 
end
```

And so on. After that, do something like this:

```
class Main 
  def start
    @modules = []
    Dir.glob("modules/*.rb") do |module_file|
        load(module_file)
        @modules << Kernel.const_get(File.basename(module_file, ".rb"))
        @modules.last.run
    end
  end
end

a = Main.new
a.start
```

Comment: thanks for this clean code, i understood how it works and i'm able to do what i wanted. Thanks